# Error while opening the Eclipse Android Layout Editor

Tags: android, eclipse, stack-overflow

Since yesterday everytime I open my layout Editor in Eclipse for the Android UI I get the following exception:

Unhandled event loop exception

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.isTheme(Unknown Source)
    at 
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.isTheme(Unknown Source)
    at...
```

the last part goes on and on as expected if an Stackoverflow Exception occurs.

Anybody else experiencing this and found a solution?
I'm working with the latests android sdk on Mac OS X with Eclipse 3.5.2

I just installed the Carbon Version of eclipse and I get this error even in this fresh copy of eclipse.

Very strange that I'm the only one experiencing this error. Maybe it is not an Eclipse problem but an problem of my project setup...

Comment: I get the same thing, on all layout files.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, and I had to dig a lot before I found a solution.  In my styles.xml I had an entry where the name and parent attributes were identical:

```
<style name="MyHeader" parent="MyHeader">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_background</item>
</style>
```

By removing the parent attribute the layout editor finally worked again:

```
<style name="MyHeader">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. Would never have found that on my own.

Comment: In my case the problem was caused by setting the parent value of a style to @style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar where changing it to @style/Theme.Sherlock fixed the problem...how very strange!

Answer (score 0):

I have not had that particular error, but I have had various project corruption problems related to resources.  Sometimes cleaning the project and rebuilding fixes it.  Sometimes I have had to revert some project files in subversion.  Sometimes just relaunching eclipse fixes things.  There is also a Fix Project Properties item in the Android Tools of the context menu that has helped once or twice.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.  Maybe an eclipse specific forum would have better answers.  Good Luck.

Comment: Could it be that you created something like a cycle? E.g. a layout which is inlucding/referencing another layout thats also includes this layout? habens to me once and there was also an StackOverflowError