# eclipse crashes on Lion os x

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-lion

Eclipse seems to be crashing all the time since I've upgraded to the Mac OS X Lion. The error I keep getting is stackoverflow.

[image]

I am using eclipse version: 1.3.1.20100916-1202 and have an open Android project at the moment of the crash. Where do I find the log file? What could be causing the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about what has changed in Lion to determine the cause of the crash. But, here's how to find the logfile:

- Window > Show View > PDE Runtime > Error Log. This gives you a view with the contents of the .log file.
- Help > About Eclipse Platform > Configuration Details. This prints out a great number of details about the environment and also concatenates the .log file. Great for including in a bug report.
- Locate the file yourself, see workspace/.metadata/.log.
- Start Eclipse using -consoleLog. This will print the messages that normally go to the .log file in the enclosing shell/command window.

Comment: Thanks a lot @retrodrone. By finding the log file, I've got the exception that was causing the crash and googled a solution. Will mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Glad I could help! Just curious, what was the exception? I may hit this with Eclipse/Lion soon.

Comment: it was an error in the android xml layout file which seemed to cause an endless loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771517/error-while-opening-the-eclipse-android-layout-editor