# Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, eclipse, stack-overflow

I am getting Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.StackOverflowError when I open xml files in layout folder in eclipse

Comment: You must provide details - please read the FAQ. What files, all XML files, examples?

Comment: check this link .,....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771517/error-while-opening-the-eclipse-android-layout-editor